# Sidekiq stops processing jobs

Tags: ruby, redis, background, sidekiq

I have a rails app which is deployed on 2 ec2 instance with nginx and capistrano. For background job, I had used sidekiq with redis. I have 50 gb RDS. I also have set max_pool_size to 50 of sidekiq concurrency. Sidekiq stops processing job when the busy queue is full. I am unable to find anything in the log. Please help find the issue

Here is Sidekiq Configuration file -

---

- :concurrency: 50
- :queues:

  - default
  - thread
  - thread1
  - [activities, 2]
  - [super_jobs, 2]
  - [thread4, 1]

Sidekiq Log -

- 2018-01-31T14:56:51.669Z 6814 TID-c5v4s Activities::StreamJob JID-20e396f7a9292a96a4e2a0e5 INFO: start
- 2018-01-31T14:56:56.801Z 6814 TID-1jby50 Activities::StreamJob JID-1da433fff954f46f317574d0 INFO: start
- 2018-01-31T14:57:06.074Z 6814 TID-1jd5vg SuperJobs::StreamJob JID-48e4a5df330bf70f10f07d1e INFO: start
- 2018-01-31T14:58:21.803Z 6814 TID-1jc1w0 SuperJobs::StreamJob JID-c4f2fa480b192aa0e34bb67a INFO: start
- 2018-01-31T14:58:22.327Z 6814 TID-c08iw Activities::StreamJob JID-00160e805f166000a801e1be INFO: start
- 2018-01-31T14:59:15.924Z 6814 TID-1bviqs SuperJobs::StreamJob JID-84d7241b62126d691c59610a INFO: start
- 2018-01-31T15:00:24.390Z 6814 TID-1jblf8 Activities::StreamJob JID-e82b4d7348b0f648bf1d079a INFO: start
- 2018-01-31T15:00:39.160Z 6814 TID-1jd7ak Activities::StreamJob JID-c8736ff182fda70f98d867f4 INFO: start

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of the workers in the web UI?

Comment: @adanot - added a screenshot